# How Easy Is It To Beat This Javascript Preventative Measure

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, code-injection

I'm trying to prevent a user from disabling style.(I HAVE A GOOD REASON TO DO THIS, so please no posts about accessibility as 99.99% of my site is totally accessible. Just tryin to prevent on .1% of my pages. and if you must know it is a paid web course that i dont want people stealing.....easily).

Im using Jquery:

```
function cssCheck() {
  if( ! $('#cssenabledcheck').is(':hidden') ) {
    window.location.href = "www.somerandompage.com";
  }
}

var styleCheck = setInterval(cssCheck, 500);
```

cssenebledcheck is an empty div with style set to hidden. The logic is if you disable styles, the div will show, and the style check will fail thus redirecting the user to a page telling them to enable styles. It is suprisingly non-memory-intensive even on old pc's, even though it is continually running every half-second.

My question is, how easy is it for a person to override (inject) the styleCheck variable, thus beating my check? I truthfully know very little about hacking so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that this can be circumvented easily by turning off JavaScript first, and *then* CSS?

Comment: Actually, i got another variable that is checked at page load to see if js is enabled. and since ya gotta reload the page to disable js, it will fail and force them to reenable javascript.

Comment: You don't need to reload the page to disable JS. I did it right now in Firefox.

Comment: If they know what they are doing, and realize that the function pointer is stored as `styleCheck`, it would only take a second to override it.

Comment: I'm sure your reasons are "good" but I have great reasons to never go to any site that attempts to hijack my browser. Whatever your reason is: rethink it. Especially since you aren't going to be able to prevent people from turning off your CSS anyway.

Comment: Why are you even storing the `setInterval` return value anywhere -- do you actually use it?

Comment: I should point out that it is also trivial to override the style of single elements on a webpage, thus leaving your `cssenabledcheck` div alone but still revealing anything else you have hidden.

Comment: Nothing is actually hidden in the div, it is just a check

Comment: What jball means is that, if I don't like what your styling is doing, I can easily override parts of it by using browser styles or the "Web Developer Toolbar" or any number of ways.  You can't depend on either styles or javascript to protect your content.

Comment: ya, i'm quickly realizing this. Well I'm gonna have to think of a better way to do this. Thanks for all the info guys

Comment: If you want to be in control, then you have to put all the logic on the server side. The user is control of anything that happens in the browser, and there's little you can do to work around that. Alternatively, you might want to rethink whether it's necessary. Are people *really* going to steal your work? And if they are, is there anything you could've done to make them pay? Wouldn't they just *not use it* if they'd been unable to steal? The net result for you would be the same. At the same time, trying to prevent the user from controlling his own browser might well cost you sales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As easy as opening firebug and issuing

```
clearInterval(styleCheck);
```

You should not assign the `setInterval` returned value to a variable though, so it would be un-clearable.. But they could rewrite the `cssCheck` method.

This in turn could be avoided by using an anonymous function

```
setInterval( function(){...}, 500);
```

but they could disable javascript altogether, and there is nothing to do about that case..

Comment: No need for firebug, just type `javascript:clearInterval(styleCheck)` into any browser's address bar

Comment: @Gaby - `for(var i=0; i< 10000; i++) clearInterval(i);` would clear the anonymous as well :) the ID is likely to be pretty low.

Comment: Couldn't add to said anonymous function a check for js enabled, and a further check at page load? or could the function still be manipulated.

Comment: Or just redeclare whatever functions you use in your anonymous function -- perhaps even going as far as to say `$ = function() { return 0; }` to disable JQuery altogether. Javascript is cool like that.

Comment: @Christian - getting rid of `$` won't disable jQuery, not if written correctly :)

Comment: That's right -- because of the anonymous function thing. I imagine doing a similar thing with the `jQuery` object will work though, right?

Answer (score 2):

It would be very easy (using [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) for example). If you truly want something to be hidden it shouldn't be on the page, period. Even if it is hidden, it is still in the source if you go toyour browser's "View Source" option.  What you have here is also easily bypassed by disabling JavaScript on one's browser.

I think the right way to do this would be to have an Ajax call to the server when you need to retrieve the hidden content, either that or go to a different page for the hidden content.

Comment: my content is protected by a php session, however i don't want people to easily disable styles, then copy and paste all the paid content.

Answer (score 2):

I could use firebug or greasemonkey to easily disable preventative measures. JavaScript can never be counted on for any sort of security.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from disabling JavaScript, one could just use Firebug to override any global variable like `styleCheck`.

Comment: So there really isn't a sure fire way to fix this?

Comment: but maybe `styleCheck` is **not** a global variable. @jimmy, keep it in a hidden scope (some anonymous function prefferably)

Answer (score 1):

Anything running in the browser must be assumed to be under the user's control.  It's trivial to use Firebug or GreaseMonkey or even a bookmarklet to change javascript variables or remove javascript functions, and even easier to alter styles (you can specify a personal stylesheet that will override the site's stylesheet).

If you truly need to protect your content from copying, you will have to display it inside a plugin such as Flash, where the environment is more tightly controlled.

Comment: I actually started making the course in flash...but man it is a pain. Oh well back to adobe land.

Comment: You could put the content into a copy-protected PDF.  Those can definitely be cracked but it will stop casual "thieves".  Or you could dynamically generate an image containing the text, although that could be fairly painful for users who want to, say, increase the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Rediculously easy.  In any JS console, type:

```
cssCheck = function() {}
```

A slightly more robust version would be to put it in a closure where it's hard to override.

```
(function() {
  function cssCheck() {
    if( ! $('#cssenabledcheck').is(':hidden') ) {
      window.location.href = "www.somerandompage.com";
    }
  }

  var styleCheck = setInterval(cssCheck, 500);
})();
```

But can still easily be beaten turning off javascript, or even `curl` or `wget`, or right click view source.  There isn't really a robust way to do what you want.